# Parellel Execution of Sequences in WSO2 ESB 5

Tags: performance, wso2, wso2-esb

In my application I use a number of mediators (md-1,2,3,4 and md-a,b,c) like (call,script, payload factory, data mapper, iterator, switch, enrich etc) to do a task. Currently mediartor md-a,b,c are opeating after mediator md-1,2,3,4 in a sequential way. And the payload returned by md-c enriches the payload returned by md-4.

But to improve the perfoamance, I'm planning to implement md-a,b,c parrelly as mentioned below. So, after md-4 it should wait until md-c completes and returns payload. Then it will enrich the payload returned by md-4 as mentioned below.

[image]

So, my basic problems are

- how to trigger and execute parrel sequence?
- how to wait until it completes?
- how to obtain the payload return by it?

I don't want a detailed answer. Any hint will be worthy a lot.

- ESB version : WSO2 5.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this scenario you can combine Clone mediator with aggregate mediator. Please check my solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="PX_ParallelTest"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <clone>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <Result1 xmlns="">
                           <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
                        </Result1>
                     </format>
                     <args/>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <loopback/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <Result2 xmlns="">
                           <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
                        </Result2>
                     </format>
                     <args/>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <loopback/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="Result" scope="default">
            <Result xmlns=""/>
         </property>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="Result" expression="$body/*[1]">
               <enrich>
                  <source clone="true" xpath="$body/*[1]"/>
                  <target type="body"/>
               </enrich>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And now you can see the response for this implementation.

```
<Result>
   <Result1>
      <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
   </Result1>
   <Result2>
      <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
   </Result2>
</Result>
```

Comment: Thank you Ernesto for the detailed answer

Answer (score 3):

how to trigger and execute parrel sequence?

- use clone mediator with 2 targets

how to wait until it completes?

- a the end of each target's sequence, call a sequence that use aggregate mediator

how to obtain the payload return by it?

- when aggregate mediator let you enter inside "onComplete", you have access to all the payloads

Comment: Thank you Jean-Michel. For the important tips. I'll try them